# i want select the ids of table1 only if it is in "column "bouquet" of table2

Tags: php, mysql

can someone make me understand
i have 2 tables,

table1 :

"id"

1

2

3

4

5

table 2 :

"bouquet"

[2,3,4,5]

i want select  "id" of table1 only if it is in "bouquet" of table2

so what sql commande i need to use ?? the result is supposed to be 2 3 4 5

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE id IN(bouquet of table2 ?????)
```

how i do this ?
can i do like this

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE id IN(SELECT bouquet FROM `table2`)
```

[table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKddg.png)

[table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLaYs.png)

Comment: Could you give us more exact table definitions? Is the `[2,3,4,5]` stored as text or is there one row for each of those four digits?

Comment: thanks for answer,  the [2,3,4,5] its stored as text ... i have add some pictures to see

Comment: That's bad database design. Is it possible for you to change the design?

Comment: A better design is to have a table containing `table2_id` and `table1_id` to connect `table2` to `table1` with a many-to-many relation.

Comment: yes maybe tell me what i have to do ?

Comment: on table2 i canot change the value cause another function insert this value on it like this [2,3,4,5]

Comment: And you cannot change that code?

Comment: no its iptv panel if i change i have to change a lot of things after, so I prefer to find a solution directly with that  [2,3,4,5]

Comment: One thing is unclear: Aren't there several rows in table2? Which row in table2 should then be used?

Comment: i just want select and display the ids of table1 only if the value of ids are on table2 column 'bouquet',     SELECT `id` FROM `table1` WHERE id IN( `table2` column 'bouquet')

Comment: Yes, but aren't there several rows in table2? Which row in table2 should be look at? All of them?

Comment: its ok men thank you for you help i have find solution but other way ...